# Setting up gradient-descent process

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, style-transfer

I am trying to set up gradient-descent process with Keras, I keep getting error:

```
from keras import backend as K 

grads = K.gradients(loss, combination_image)[0]
fetch_loss_and_grads = K.function([combination_image], [loss, grads])
```

This is my error message:

```
tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use tf.GradientTape instead.
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal piece of code so that we can reproduce it on our side? It does force you to work a bit on it, but in exchange the error is generalizable to cases other than yours

Comment: If you are using Tensorflow 2, which eager execution is enabled by default, you should use ``tf.GradientTape()`` syntax instead.

Comment: You could consider posting your question in Data Science: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/